# Bulk insert in Django Rest Framework JSONAPI

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I'm implementing a **DRFJSonAPI API**: https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

However, I got stuck on trying to implement a bulk insert, it seems that the [JSONAPI specification](https://jsonapi.org/) doesn't mention anything about it
I found only this referring to it as an experimental feature: https://springbot.github.io/json-api/extensions/bulk/

and it doesn't seem to be implemented by DRF JSONAPI

I've tried several approaches, from the basic of having a new @action defined on my viewset, to even just adding the DRF api_view and going from there.
But what it looks like is that my serializer doesn't understand correctly the data and returns an empty dictionary.

My serializers:

```py
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers, relations, views

class VideoScriptRowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    included_serializers = {
        'video': 'videos.serializers.VideoOnDemandSerializer',
    }

    class Meta:
        model = VideoScriptRow
        fields = (
            'video_id',
            'index',
            'character',
            'guessed',
            'is_locked',
            'loop',
            'text',
            'time_start',
        )


class VideoOnDemandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    script_rows = relations.ResourceRelatedField(
        queryset=VideoScriptRow.objects,  # queryset argument is required
        required=False,
        many=True,
    )
    included_serializers = {
        'script_rows': 'videos.serializers.VideoScriptRowSerializer',
    }

    class Meta:
        model = VideoOnDemand
        fields = (
            'title',
            'workflow_status',
            'initial_offset',
            'video_offset',
            'video_input',
            'thumbnail_url',
            'transcript_uri',
            'created_at',
            'script_rows',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'workflow_status')
```

My views:

```py
    from rest_framework_json_api.views import ModelViewSet, RelationshipView

    class VideoScriptRowViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        queryset = VideoScriptRow.objects.all()
        serializer_class = VideoScriptRowSerializer


    class VideoOnDemandViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        queryset = VideoOnDemand.objects.all()
        serializer_class = VideoOnDemandSerializer
```

Based on DRF documentation it seems that you just need to pass many=True to a serializer instance in order to have bulk creation, but all the examples I found were about serializing to show a list of the objects, not about deserializing the data coming from a POST.

I hava also tried directly inheriting from ListSerializer and creating a ViewSet only for this action... still nothing on my request.data when I use a list of items

My last attempt was simply adding an @api_view decorator, as I thought it would be immune to DRF JSONAPi, but still nothing on my `request.data`

The api_view implementation:

```py
@api_view(['post'])
def update_script_rows(request):
    serializer = VideoScriptRowSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)  # request.data is empty here
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    # Here goes the bulk insertion
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The test implementation that is calling the view:

```py
    def test_update_script_rows(self):
        self.client.login(email='foobar@invalid.com', password='secretpassword')
        url = reverse('update-script-rows')

        response = self.client.post(
            url,
            {
                'data': [{
                    'type': 'VideoScriptRow',
                    'attributes': {
                        'index': 1,
                        'video_id': self.v1.id,
                        'character': 'johndoe',
                        'text': 'hello, world2',
                    }
                }],
            },
            format='vnd.api+json'
        )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

If this action is on the `VideoScriptRowViewSet` I can see the data in request.data when it is a single object, but when it is a list I see nothing.
If I do it on the @api_view I get an error: rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.Conflict: `The resource object's type (VideoScriptRow) is not the type that constitute the collection represented by the endpoint (UpdateScriptRows).`
Even after changing the base class of my serializer from DRFJSONAPI to DRF, there are links to DRFJSONAPI somewhere else that I fail to see.

Any idea how can I easily achieve this bulk creation on DRFJSONAPi? My best idea now is to get rid o JSONAPI and do everything on plain DRF, but I would like to keep the JSONAPI structure if possible

Comment: Have you tried [DRF Multiple Object Creation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create) ?

Comment: I did =/ when I mentioned the ListSerializer, I did similar to the example in this part of the documentation

Comment: the issue with the ListSerializer not working was related to the default parser in the settings still being json_api parser, if I remove that one, it works... however I still can't make the bulk insert with jsonapi

Comment: The [Bulk Extension](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/blob/9c7a03dbc37f80f6ca81b16d444c960e96dd7a57/extensions/bulk/index.md) was part of an experimental extension feature in JSON:API. That one has been removed. It will most likely be replaced by [another implementation of extensions](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#extensions) in upcoming `v1.1`. The [Atomic Operations official extension](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1437) is proposed for the same release and would support your use case. If implementing such a feature, I would target that one and not the old version.